# shopify buy button js productSet with variants

Tags: javascript, buybutton.js

How to create buy button with productSet and their variants?
Example:

```
 ui.createComponent('productSet', {
                id: ['123123213', '56456554'],
                variantId: ['something']
                node: document.getElementById('product-component-1614879512289'),
                moneyFormat: '%E2%82%AC%7B%7Bamount_with_comma_separator%7D%7D',
                options: {
```